# How to connect Rpi-3 and Microstack GPS

Tags: pi-3, gps

How to connect and program my RPi3 to a Microstack Base and GPS?

I have tried for the last 3 weeks to run any/all scripts to operate a Microstack Base and GPS L80 with my Rpi-3.

After seeing a lot of posts, I'm starting to think there is a bug in either the MIcrostack board or in the Rpi-3 itself. I have purchased a number of these items for instruction and was counting on the the two items to work!

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a solution.
This article was very usefull for me

http://spellfoundry.com/2016/05/29/configuring-gpio-serial-port-raspbian-jessie-including-pi-3/#comment-67160

and i recommand you to read it

Now on RPI3 the Serial port

- ttyAMA0 is used by BlueTooth
- ttySO refers to the GPIO
- The Alias Serial0 refers to the GPIO both on RPI2 and RPI3.

So :

after a reinstallation of Jessie with a recent version to be sure all is clean

as usual

```
$ sudo apt-get update 
$ sudo apt-get upgrade

$ sudo  raspi-config
```

go to  Advanced options : 
Would you like a login shell to be accessible over serial?
 response "yes" (not as in the microstack datasheet )

```
$ sudo apt-­get install python3-­microstacknode
```

To install the gpsd standard tools

```
$ sudo apt­-get install gpsd gpsd-­clients python­-gps
```

edit GPSD by

```
$ sudo nano /etc/default/gpsd
```

and put the options :

```
START_DAEMON="true"
USBAUTO="false"
DEVICES="/dev/serial0"
GPSD_OPTIONS="-n -G"
```

equally

```
$ sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt
```

remove

```
console=serial0,115200
```

and save

```
$ sudo nano /boot/config.txt
```

you must have at the end

```
enable_uart=1
```

Disable the console by

```
$ sudo systemctl stop serial-getty@ttyS0.service
$ sudo systemctl disable serial-getty@ttyS0.service
```

i have equally done 
`$ sudo chmod 775 ../../dev/ttySO`
 ( i dont know if it is really necessary )

and obviously a reboot

and miracle the gps works with

```
 cgps -s
```

NB:  you must have a fix on the GPS ( the red led flashes )

Answer (score 0):

The [Microstack GPS](http://www.microstack.org.uk/products/microstack-gps/#techspecs) uses the serial GPIO connections. These have [changed](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/553) with the Raspberry Pi 3.

I'd contact [Microstack](http://www.microstack.org.uk/) and ask for their workaround/solution.